# Error: missing return value in Java

Tags: java, methods

So I've built a method to find prime numbers.  It seems to work only when i forcible mark it as true.  However when I leave it as I would like it, the compiler disagrees.

How do I satisfy the missing return value error?

```
private static boolean isPrime( int n)
    // write a loop that sets a loop variable named divisor that goes from 2 to n/2
    // in the loop call isFactor to see if divisor divides n evenly
    // if it does print out that divisor followed by a space (no newline)
    {
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= n; divisor++)
        {
            boolean prime = true;   
            for (int i = 2; i < divisor; i++)
            {
                if (isFactor(n, divisor))
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }

        }
        return true; // i just put this here so it would compile at all
    }
```

Comment: what if doesn't go into for loop runtime ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the loop ends without hitting that `return false;`?

Comment: @JigarJoshi i'm not understanding your question

Comment: @user2357112 I expect it to come up as true and only return the prime numbers.

Comment: You can only satisfy it by ensuring that the method always returns a value. In this case, if your `for` loop conditions were not met, the program would never enter it and no return statement would be available.

Comment: Java compiler always ensure that you must return a value if you are giving a return type in the method. That is why, it needs to be satisfied as there may be conditions when no value is returned on loop's unsatisfied conditions.

Comment: @Tom I see. So what do I do then?

Comment: @WeekzGod: Why would you expect it to return true if you never have a statement that returns true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your method `isFactor()` work, this is how you should do it

```
private static boolean isPrime( int n)
{
    boolean prime = true;

    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= n; divisor++)
    {          
        for (int i = 2; i < divisor; i++)
        {
            if (isFactor(n, divisor))
            {
               prime =false;
            }
        }
    }
    return prime;
}
```

---

By the way, I will do my `isPrime()` method as simple as this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n){
    for(int i = 2 ; i < n ; i++){
        if(n % i == 0){
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but you'll run isFactor() several times after you've already identified a number as not being prime.

Comment: yes I know there should be a `break` there, but I just let it be like that since OP didn't include the `isFactor()` code

Answer (score 3):

If your loop never executes, you never return anything, and you told Java that you would return *something*, regardless of whether or not your logic did whatever.

Look at your code between curly braces inside of the method as blocks that may or may not get executed during the lifetime of your program.  If you remove the entire `for` block, you don't have any valid return statement that Java can use to say, "Yes, if everything fails, then I can use this value."

That is to say, your code could behave like this in one run:

```
public boolean isPrime(int n) {
    // outer for block is removed
}
```

...then like this in another run:

```
public boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= n; divisor++) {
        // inner for block is removed
    }
}
```

... and so forth, until you reconstruct the entire method.

In all of the above code snippets, if neither the outer nor inner block are executed (and, by extension, the `if` statement), then your program doesn't return anything on all paths.

This is formally specified in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7), §8.4.7:

> **If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).**
>
> *In other words, a method with a return type must return only by using a return statement that provides a value return; it is not allowed to "drop off the end of its body".*

Comment: That's not the point. Of course his loop will execute. The problem is for values where isFactor() always returns false. Then his program would never return a value unless the "return true" statement is there.

Comment: The compiler doesn't believe that the loop will *always* execute, though.  If `n == 1` for instance, then the loop *won't* fire.  Now, I'm not arguing about the correctness of the method to find primes; I'm merely stating syntatic fact.

Comment: There are values of n where the loop won't fire. You're correct. But there are also values of n where the loop will fire and the program would still fall through to the final return statement.

Comment: Yes, I realize this.  But again, **I'm not talking about the correctness of the program.  I'm _only_ talking about syntax.**  The question as presented to me was exclusively about syntax.

Comment: I'm also talking about syntax. My point is the "return true" is required for both the for-loop path and the if-statement path. Your answer only called out the for-loop path.

Comment: Syntatically no, it doesn't.  *Semantically*, it better have, or you've got an infinite loop on your hands.  Syntax isn't the same as semantics, and once again, I stress that I'm only talking about syntax.

Comment: You're incorrect, there's no infinite loop. Both loops increment a value and end once the value is incremented past a certain point. Neither of those are a candidate for infinite loops. But you could make it all the way through both loops without isFactor() ever returning false, in which case you'd reach the final return true statement. That's a syntax problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58310/discussion-between-makoto-and-cameron).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it in this way. Since you return false in inside a if condition, program shoud get to know if its not goes to if condition what should i return.

```
private static boolean myMethod( int n)
  boolean flag = true;
    // some code here

    flag = false;

     //  again some code here

    flag = true

     // Finally return the flag

    return flag;

}
```

Edited

In your case you can use it like this

```
 private static boolean isPrime( int n)
{
boolean flag = true;

for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= n; divisor++)
{          
    for (int i = 2; i < divisor; i++)
    {
        if (isFactor(n, divisor))
        {
           flag =false;
        }
    }
}
return flag;
 }
```

Comment: It's a requirement of the assignment that I use the method I built. The "isFactor" method is required to be part of the isPrime method.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is perfectly valid, but only with the `return true` statement. Without the `return true` statement, your program would never find primes; it would correctly identify numbers as not being prime, or it would just not return anything. It would also decide to not return anything if a value less than 2 were passed in for `n`. Thankfully the compiler will not let you decide not to return anything when you have given a non-void return type (unless you throw an exception but that's beside the point).

So the way your code is written is fine. You identify non-prime numbers by trying to find a divisor, and immediately return back when you've found one. And if you don't find one, the last statement in your program declares a prime number found by process of elimination. You will want to examine your inner for-loop, though. It doesn't change the arguments  passed into isFactor() so it's completely irrelevant. This would work just as well and be a lot more efficient:

```
private static boolean isPrime( int n)
// write a loop that sets a loop variable named divisor that goes from 2 to n/2
// in the loop call isFactor to see if divisor divides n evenly
// if it does print out that divisor followed by a space (no newline)
{
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= n; divisor++)
    {
       if (isFactor(n, divisor))
       {
         return false;
       }
    }
    return true; // i just put this here so it would compile at all
}
```